Select the first occurrence of a tag but igoring the hierarchy using CSS
I've stumbled upon this question about CSS selector. Which is to select the first occurrence of <span> but igoring its hierarchy. I know I could use JavaScript to document.querySelectorAll('span') to get the first DOM object and assign class to it. But is there a way to achieve it avoid using JavaScript?
The HTML structure is arbitrary, so selectors like div:first-child > p:first-of-type > div:first-of-type span:first-of-type is too specific. I want the selector works even when HTML structure is changed.
I have tried something like this, but I'm not sure why MISS ME 4 is also selected.


span:first-of-type:not(:has(span):nth-child(n+2 of :has(span)) span) {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div>
  <h1>Select the first occurrence of span</h1>
  <p>
    <span>HIT ME</span>
    <div>
      <span>MISS ME 1</span>
      <span>MISS ME 2</span>
      <span>MISS ME 3</span>
    </div>
    <span>MISS ME 4</span>
    <span>MISS ME 5</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 6</span>
    <span>MISS ME 7</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 7</span>
    <span>MISS ME 8</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 9</span>
    <span>MISS ME 10</span>
    <span>MISS ME 11</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 12</span>
    <span>MISS ME 13</span>
    <span>MISS ME 14</span>
    <div>
      <span>MISS ME 15</span>
      <span>MISS ME 16</span>
      <span>MISS ME 17</span>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>



Is it even possible? I'm completely out of ideas.

I cannot really imagine a use case for this? I'm sure there is, but it can be helpful to know what you're trying to do. The normal way to do this would be to add a class or id to the first element and select that in your CSS.

doesn't sound doable. Even if it does I think it would be too long and not worth it

@KIKOSoftware Sorry that it's not practical but a "is it possible" question just out of curiocity.

To select the first span in a document select the span element that:

is not preceded by a sibling span element
is not preceded by a sibling element that contains a span element
doesn't have an ancestor that's a span element
doesn't have an ancestor that's preceded by a sibling span element
doesn't have an ancestor that's preceded by a sibling element that contains a span element

Use:
span:not(span ~ span):not(:has(span) ~ span):not(span span):not(span ~ * span):not(:has(span) ~ * span)



span:not(span ~ span):not(:has(span) ~ span):not(span span):not(span ~ * span):not(:has(span) ~ * span) {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div>
  <h1>Select the first occurrence of span</h1>
  <p>
    <span>HIT ME</span>
    <div>
      <span>MISS ME 1</span>
      <span>MISS ME 2</span>
      <span>MISS ME 3</span>
    </div>
    <span>MISS ME 4</span>
    <span>MISS ME 5</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 6</span>
    <span>MISS ME 7</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 7</span>
    <span>MISS ME 8</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 9</span>
    <span>MISS ME 10</span>
    <span>MISS ME 11</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 12</span>
    <span>MISS ME 13</span>
    <span>MISS ME 14</span>
    <div>
      <span>MISS ME 15</span>
      <span>MISS ME 16</span>
      <span>MISS ME 17</span>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>




Now I see, I forgot the cases of when span:first-of-type is preceded by another tag but contains <span>. These 4 :not conditions make so much sense. Thanks for the answer.

I think you can simplify to span:first-of-type:not(:has(span) ~ *):not(span ~ * *):not(:has(span) ~ * *)

also with nesting to avoid repeating the span span {  &:first-of-type:not(:has(&) ~ *):not(& ~ * *):not(:has(&) ~ * *) {} }

@HaoWu - I've amended this answer. I missed the case where a span element is a descendant of another span element.

@TemaniAfif - Sure. I'm not convinced those are simpler or easier to follow though.

Also I just realized that <div> cannot be a child of <p> so the actual structure is a little bit off, but the concept remains.

I end up with the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79140718/8620333 even if it's not easier/simpler, it can be used like a function where you adjust the selector only once.

A more generic version that should work with classes as well:


.target { /* update what you want to select here (class, tag, etc) */
  &:nth-child(1 of &):not(:has(&) ~ * *):not(:has(&) ~ *):not(& ~ * *):not(& *) {
    border-color: red;
  }
}

div {
  padding-inline: 15px;
}
.target {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
<div>Some content</div>
<div class="target">
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>
    <div class="target">Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div class="target">Some content</div>
  </div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="target">
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="target">Some content</div>
  <div class="target">Some content</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="target">
    <div class="target">Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div class="target">Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="target">
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div class="target">Some content</div>
    <div>Some content
      <div>Some content</div>
      <div class="target">Some content</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>Some content</div>
          <div>Some content</div>
          <div>Some content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="target">
      <div class="target">Some content</div>
      <div>Some content</div>
      <div>Some content</div>
    </div>
  </div>



Applied to your example:


span { 
  &:nth-child(1 of &):not(:has(&) ~ * *):not(:has(&) ~ *):not(& ~ * *):not(& *)  {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
<div>
  <h1>Select the first occurrence of span</h1>
  <p>
    <span>HIT ME</span>
    <span>
      <span>MISS ME 1</span>
      <span>MISS ME 2</span>
      <span>MISS ME 3</span>
    </span>
    <span>MISS ME 4</span>
    <span>MISS ME 5</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 6</span>
    <span>MISS ME 7</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 7</span>
    <span>MISS ME 8</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 9</span>
    <span>MISS ME 10</span>
    <span>MISS ME 11</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>MISS ME 12</span>
    <span>MISS ME 13</span>
    <span>MISS ME 14</span>
    <span>
      <span>MISS ME 15</span>
      <span>MISS ME 16</span>
      <span>MISS ME 17</span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>




Similar concept but with intuitive and easy-to-refactor syntax. Thanks for the great answer!

You're missing the "doesn't have an ancestor that's preceded by a sibling .target element" case. Add :not(& ~ * *) to fix.

@Alohci I think we don't need it. Can you give me an example to illustrate that case? I am trying different combination but not easy to find them all.

Sure. Check this: https://jsbin.com/jikecitoxu/edit?html,css,output

@Alohci ok, I see
